# Check of Monotone Property

Tags: monotone-functions

I would like to check whether $f: \Bbb [-\pi/2, \pi/2] \in \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ where $f(x) = \tan x$ is monotone increasing function.

Of course it looks fairly true in my bare eye with denoted in the printed version of textbook, however, want to show it from the ground.

Which approach is a valid sense to show the monotone property in this case and general case also?

Comment: Have you tried to check whether its prime derivative is positive?

Comment: Actually, $\tan$ is not a function with domain $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$ and codomain $\Bbb R$ to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $f'(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}>0$ for all $x$ from the given interval
we use the Quotient rule: $$\tan(x))'=\frac{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}>0$$

Comment: hm.. ${d\over dx}\tan x={d\over dx}{\sin x \over \cos x} = {d\over dx}(-1){-\sin x \over \cos x}= {d\over dx}(-1){1\over t}{dt \over dx}$ where $t = \cos x$ I think I almost had forgotten how to do differentiate with a parameters.. any help?

Comment: ah.. it looks better to use a quotient rule..

Answer (score 0):

The domain should be $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Since $\displaystyle f'(x)=\sec^2x>0$ for all $\displaystyle x\in\left(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, $f( x)$ is (strictly) increasing.

Alternatively, for $\pi/2\le x\le y\le\pi/2$,

\begin{align}
f(y)-f(x)&=\frac{\sin y}{\cos y}-\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\\
&=\frac{\sin y\cos x-\cos y\sin x}{\cos y\cos x}\\
&=\frac{\sin(y-x)}{\cos y\cos x}\\
\end{align}

Note that $\displaystyle y-x\in(0,\pi)$. So, we have $\sin(y-x)>0$.

Since $\cos y\cos x>0$, $f(y)>f(x)$.

$f$ is (strictly) increasing.